# How do I send mass mail in cakephp without using sendgrid

Tags: php, email, cakephp, massmail

This is my html template

```
Dear ##name##(##email##),

Thank you for contacting us.
```

I want to replace ##name## and ##email## with the receiver's name and email of the person who gets it which will be provided in the array. How do I do it?

This is what I've got so far

```
$to_email = array('a@example.com', 'b@example.com', 'c@example.com');
$to_name = array('apple', 'ball', 'cat');

$Email = new CakeEmail();
$Email->from($from);
$Email->to($to_email );
$Email->subject($subject);
$Email->emailFormat('html');
$Email->viewVars(array('data' => $body));
$Email->template('bulk');
$Email->send();
```

Comment: `This is my html template` It should look like any other view file - start from that basis and you have a chance of it working.

Comment: Yes, I know about that, but I want to be able to replace some variable in the template with the receiver's name or may be directly echo receiver's name, without using loop.

Comment: Well, it doesn't work like that. Logically you are asking to send 3 emails (because the contents are different). You can't send 3 emails with different contents without .... sending **3** emails.

Answer (score 2):

You should start with creating [template](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/email.html#sending-templated-emails) for your email, which will be including your current content (I use name `example_template.ctp` in my samples below):

```
Dear <?php echo $name; ?> <?php echo $email; ?>,

Thank you for contacting us.
```

Then you have to modify way of setting up your `viewVars()` and `template()`:

```
$Email->viewVars(array('email' => $email, 'name' => $name));
$Email->template('example_template');
```

There is also required to change way of sending emails to loop over emails instead of sending all recipients in one field. So combine your input arrays into one, e.g.:

```
$emails = array(
    'a@example.com' => 'apple',
    'b@example.com' => 'ball',
    'c@example.com' => 'cat'
);
```

Then just foreach over your array and send mails:

```
$Email = new CakeEmail();

foreach ($emails as $email => $name) {
    $Email->from($from);
    $Email->to($email);
    $Email->subject($subject);
    $Email->emailFormat('html');
    $Email->viewVars(array('email' => $email, 'name' => $name));
    $Email->template('example_template');
    $Email->send();
    $Email->reset(); // for cleaning up CakeEmail object
}
```

Comment: Can't this be done without using loop like sendgrid? Because using loop if we send say thousands email at the same time then the system will hang.
I appreciate your answer but I was looking for the other solution.

Comment: Do you send this mails directly from controller action? You probably should move this feature to Shell and create cronjob, so whole action sending mailing will be done in background.

Comment: I am not used to with this Shell thing. Can you give me a quick example for this?

Comment: Start with this [Creating a shell](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/console-and-shells.html#creating-a-shell). You need to move your email sending logic to shell. If you retrieve emails from database, you can also easily move this code there. If you finish creating it, all you need to send mailing will be typing in the console command ./Console/cake Mailing send (if your shell has name MailingShell and has method send()).

Comment: So email has to be sent from console command? but I have to be able to send the message from the application. The email has to be sent whenever the user chose to send email with multiple email address selected from the form. And I wanted this without loop. Can this be done?

Comment: I think it's imposible, because you want to send differrent content to differenet users. Your code sends one email to many recipients but with same content. Also it has everyone in `To:` field what is not good for privacy. To keep loop and shell sending by user from from, you can add additional field to your table (I hope you store there your mails) which will be indicate that someone want to send email to this person. Then create a shell which will be select emails by this field and send in loop. Last step is to create cronjob which will be execute this shell for example by each 5 minutes.

Comment: You should _definitely_ be sending emails in the background (via a cli) - via the web the only thing you'd ordinarily do is create the job for the background-worker to process.

Comment: [link](https://sendgrid.com/blog/guest-post-sendgrid-takes-the-cakephp-when-it-comes-to-smtp/) here is the link, this is what I wanted to be able to do, it says to use its own host, and user. I didn't used the one it mentioned, may be that is why its not replacing the variables. Can something like this be done?